# Excel - Search through a column to find if text matches and then add corresponding cell

Tags: excel, formula, worksheet

I want to add values from 1 worksheet to another.

The first worksheet ("November 2011") simply contains name & price, names are however duplicated and the sum needs to be added on the second worksheet ("Sales").

e.g. "November 2011"

```
    A           B
1   Name        Price
2   McDonalds   10
3   McDonalds   10
4   Burger King 20
5   Burger King 30
6   Wendys      5
7   iHop        20
8   iHop        15
```

The second worksheet ("Sales") contains only 2 columns also Name & Price. However, Name has had duplicates removed.

e.g. "Sales"

```
    A           B
1   Name        Price
2   McDonalds   
3   Burger King 
4   Wendys      
5   iHop
```

I need a formula to sum the totals from the first worksheet "November 2011" onto the Price for the second worksheet "Sales".

I have used this formula =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,Sales!A1:A8)),'November 2011'!D2,"") but it only matches the text for a single row.

What I want is a formula which does this:

"Sales"

```
    A           B
1   Name        Price
2   McDonalds   20
3   Burger King 50
4   Wendys      5
5   iHop        35
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `SUMIF`, which takes the following format:

```
=SUMIF(<some_range>, <some_critiera>, <range_to_sum>)
```

In your case, you would put this formula in cell `B2` on the sheet `Sales`:

```
=SUMIF('November 2011'!$A$2:$A$8,A2,'Nov 2011'!$B$2:$B$8)
```

Or to make it a bit more flexible by incorporating the entire range:

```
=SUMIF('Nov 2011'!A:A,A2,'Nov 2011'!B:B)
```